# jQuery set height of variable height navbar for body and class used on anchors so that nav doesn't cover up target

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got this script below which upon load and resize sets the padding of the body and a class used on anchors so that the navbar doesn't cover up the target. This is for navbars with fluid images and those heights are variable, that's why I created this script but I am not so hot with jQuery.

*Question: I can't figure out how to get it less repetitive, the load and the resize, can't they work so I don't have to repeat?*

**Link: http://jsbin.com/iJaJAzIM/1/edit**

```
//Adjust body and .anchortarget so that navbar doesn't cover up anchor

$(window).load(function () {
  $('body').css({
     "padding-top": $(".navbar").height() + "px"
  });

  $('.anchortarget').css({
     "padding-top": $(".navbar").height() + "px"
  }, {
     "margin-top": $(".navbar").height() - "px"
  });

});

$(window).resize(function () {
  $('body').css({
      "padding-top": $(".navbar").height() + "px"
  });

 $('.anchortarget').css({
    "padding-top": $(".navbar").height() + "px"
  }, {
    "margin-top": $(".navbar").height() - "px"
  });

 });
```

Comment: `$(window).on('resize load', function() {...`

Comment: Upgraded: http://jsbin.com/iJaJAzIM/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is in the first comment from @adeneo and the result is in the third comment by me.**

```
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
  $('body').css({
    "padding-top": $(".navbar").height() + "px"
  });

  $('.anchortarget').css({
    "padding-top": $(".navbar").height() + "px"
  }, {
     "margin-top": $(".navbar").height() - "px"
  });
});
```